# Click passes through to underlaying view

Tags: android, popup, android-relativelayout

which is added to `rootView = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);` using method [rootView.addView(View child)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29).

Here is it's layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/popup"
        android:layout_width="284dp"
        android:layout_height="302dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ll_popup_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

/* Some textviews, imageviews etc */

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When this pop-up is added, if it overlays some other views (e.g. button), when clicked on some area of the pop-up (e.g. textview), the underlying view is getting the event (button is clicked, edittext is popping up the keyboard and getting focused).

Is there anyway to avoid it?

Comment: Make the outer most `ViewGroup` clickable and add `android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"` to disable the click sound.

Comment: @Emmanuel thanks. that worked. could you please add this as an answer, so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the outer most `ViewGroup` clickable and add`android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"` to disable the click sound.